# How can I get all users signed up in angularfire2

Tags: angular, angularfire2

Now I just want to get all users from firebase. I can sign up using angularfire2 to the firebase. And I want to get the user information with the uid after I login as another user.
Is it possible?
If not, how can I manage the users in firebase using angularfire2 such as deleting and editing the existed users?

Answer (score 0):

You can not. The only way to achieve this is to write the user into new object in firebase after a registration and set key to be user's UID. When you do that, you will have a possibility to read all users and their data.

Comment: That is very helpful. I want to ask you one more. If I am going to edit the existing user's info such as editing, deleting and etc, how should I do?

For example, if I delete any user using firebase sdk, then the user will be existed in the firebase console. Isn't there the way to delete that or edit?

Comment: PS: if I delete one user, in the firebase console, the user info will be existed continuously. Then next time when the user sign up with the email, then the user will get this message "the email is existed" from firebase sdk.

Is there any way to delete the user with uid?

Comment: You can delete it directly from firebase website auth page.